# Query to convert a key-value table into a human-readable one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I must not be using the right keywords in my searches because I cannot find anything.

I have a table which looks like the following:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| ID | entry_num | field_num | value          |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 23 |        11 |         1 |  joe@gmail.com |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 24 |        11 |         2 |             24 |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 25 |        11 |         3 |           blue |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 26 |        12 |         1 |    sue@aol.com |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 27 |        12 |         2 |             32 |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

I'd like to build a **QUERY** which returns the results like this:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----+-------+
| entry_num | email         | age | color |
+-----------+---------------+-----+-------+
|        11 | joe@gmail.com | 24  | blue  |
+-----------+---------------+-----+-------+
|        12 | sue@aol.com   | 32  | NULL  |
+-----------+---------------+-----+-------+
```

I know I will need to manually convert the `field_num` to the corresponding `column` names, but I have that list (on paper, sadly it's not another table).

Anyone know how to do this?  I'm it's been solved before (and asked, but as I said I cannot find the questions!) and I hate to try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, perhaps it is not the best solution, but it give you what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT entry_num,(SELECT VALUE FROM your_tab t2 WHERE t2.entry_num = t1.entry_num
AND t2.field_num = 1)  AS email,
(SELECT VALUE FROM your_tab t2 WHERE t2.entry_num = t1.entry_num AND t2.field_num = 2)  AS age,
(SELECT VALUE FROM your_tab t2 WHERE t2.entry_num = t1.entry_num AND t2.field_num = 3) as color
 FROM your_tab t1
```

Comment: That works, but is there a way to query on the columns at the end?  Basically appending an `WHERE age>30` ?

Comment: Answered my own question: use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`